# How can I set dynamic checkbox in web page

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, checkbox, model

How can I set the dynamic checkbox into table rows when the data given from a modal using java script

```
function CreateCheckBox(){

    //Second create a&nbsp;row
    var row = document.tbody.tr;
    row.className = 'gridrow';

    //Third create td&nbsp;element
    td = document.tbody.tr.td;
    td.className = 'gridcell';

    td.rowSpan = 1;
    td.style.width = '80px';

    //fourth create checkbox in that td element
    var chkbox = document.createElement('input');
    chkbox.type = "checkbox";
    chkbox.id = "chk"&nbsp;
    chkbox.name = "chk"&nbsp;

    //Fifth add checkbox to td element
    td.appendChild(chkbox);
    //Add a td into a row
    row.appendChild(td);
    //Finally added to&nbsp;the form to print

}
```

```
<table
    id="example"
    class="form-table"
    class="display select"
    cellspacing="2"
    cellpadding="10">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>CID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>TP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody
    id="tableB"
    data-toggle="checkbox"
    onclick="CreateCheckBox()">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but I cant get check box when the entered data from a model in web page.. this is table in index page..
After that I coded java script for data adding in table

Comment: i f `<tbody ...` is empty, there is no possibility to click on

Comment: `chkbox.id = "chk"&nbsp;;` is JS syntax error, otherwise ID MUST BE UNIQUE !

Comment: sorry for my all mistakes..I would be grateful to you, If you could help me for resolving it

Answer (score 0):

Every time you want to add any row call `createCheckBox` with the excepted parameters.Hope it will work.

```js
function createCheckBox(cid, name, address, tp) {
  var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + cid + "</td><td>" + name + "</td> <td>" + address + "</td><td>" + tp + "</td></tr>";
  $(markup).appendTo("#example tbody");
}
createCheckBox(1, 'fafa', 'add', 'Tp1');
createCheckBox(2, 'fafa2', 'add2', 'Tp12');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="form-table display select" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="10">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Checkbox</th>
      <th>CID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>TP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

At the end of the script, I call `createCheckBox` two times with different value. So you can notice two rows in the table.